# How to implement the edge button pointer event?

Tags: xaml, button, uwp, microsoft-edge

[image: Edge Buttons]

I have seen this kind of button styling only in edge button and would like to know how to implement it. So there are two different effects into play(as far as I know). First that when buttons are pressed the content inside them shrinks (unlike default effect provided by Windows) and then second a dark non-discrete border appears inside the button when clicked to almost give a feel of depth in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was a challenge!

My first idea was to use the `UWP Community Toolkit` `DropShadowPanel` to create a shadow and clip it to the button's rectangle. Unfortunately this didn't work well, as I would have to set the shadow on a `Rectangle` that would need to have a visible border, which is not really good for our purpose of having a nicely blended borderless button. In addition, the `DropShadowPanel` shadow just didn't give a strong enough shadow effect that would be enough for the button to look like in Edge.

I have used Visual Studio and attached it's debugger to the Edge browser to see which control does the browser actually use. The `Live Tree Visualizer` revealed this:

[image: SpartanXAML.InnerShadowControl]

`SpartanXAML.InnerShadowControl`? Okay, we don't have that. Let's work around this.

I fired up Photoshop instead. Created a 64x64 square image, put a transparent rectangle layer on the surface and set its `Inner Glow` as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Inner Glow]

After export, I got the following PNG:

[image: Glow]

That looks quite like the inner shadow on the Edge button!

Now let's create a custom button style that uses this image!

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="EdgeButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#f5f5f5" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Width="64" Height="64" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c1c1c0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#c1c1c0" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleX">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.8" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="Scale" Storyboard.TargetProperty="ScaleY">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.8" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="InnerShadow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>


                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
            AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">
                        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:Scale x:Name="Scale"
                                    ScaleX="1"
                                    ScaleY="1"
                                    CenterX="32"
                                    CenterY="32"
                                    Duration="100"
                                    Delay="0"
                                    EasingType="Default"
                                    AutomaticallyStart="True"/>
                        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </ContentPresenter>

                    <Image Source="/Assets/InnerShadowGray.png" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="InnerShadow" />

                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is a lengthy listing so I will just point out the most interesting things:

- Removed all borders from the button
- Set background to `#f5f5f5` and hover background to `#c1c1c0` to match Edge
- Set the width and height to 64
- Added an `Image` as the last control in the `RootGrid`, this is the shadow image, is `Collapsed` by default and appears only when pointer is pressed
- Used UWP Community Toolkit's (`Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls` NuGet package) `Scale` behavior to create a simple, easy to control animation. This required adding `xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"` and `xmlns:behaviors="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animations.Behaviors"` XML namespaces to the root element of the file
- Replaced the default `PointerDownThemeAnimation` with a custom animation utilizing `Scale` behavior, to make the animation more significant and scale uniformly, without skewing the content

Now let's just take our new button for a test ride!

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource EdgeButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Image Source="Assets/Windows.png" />
</Button>
```

And the result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Wow, really helpful answer! I can't wait but implement it.

Comment: Let me know how it went :-)